# Issue with complex Update Query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE CHILD_COND
    SET S_TRD=
      (SELECT S_TRD
      FROM
        (SELECT MAX(TV.S_TRD)            AS S_TRD,
        TV.TRADEID                        AS TRADEID,
        TV.TRD_VER             AS TRD_VER,
        TV.TIMEST                 AS TIMEST,
        TV.SOURCENAME                     AS SOURCENAME,
        STG_TRADE.SP_COND AS SP_COND
        FROM MASTER_T TV,
        T_STG_TRADE_VERSION STG_TRADE
        WHERE TV.SOURCENAME       = STG_TRADE.SOURCENAME
        AND TV.TRADEID            = STG_TRADE.TRADEID
        AND TV.TRD_VER = STG_TRADE.TRD_VER
        AND TV.TIMEST     = STG_TRADE.TIMEST
        AND TRADESETID            = '91004'
        GROUP BY TV.TRADEID,
        TV.TRD_VER,
        TV.TIMEST,
        TV.SOURCENAME,
         STG_TRADE.SP_COND
        )TRD WHERE CHILD_COND.SP_COND = TRD.SP_COND AND S_TRD IS NOT NULL
     )
```

I need to update the foreign key in the child table based on the primary key from the master table.
But when there is no value in the child table, all the child foreign key value is getting updated to null.
S_TRD is being set to null when new master records are inserted in MASTER_T but there are no corresponding child records in CHILD_COND

Comment: Why dont you try joining with CHILD_COND in your from clause in the most inner query this way you would only run the update on the master records with children

Comment: Can you please provide me some sample.I am not an expert in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `MERGE` statement will cater that ,only matched and not null S_TRD get updated to `child_cond` table

```
MERGE INTO CHILD_COND cc
     USING (  SELECT MAX (TV.S_TRD) AS S_TRD,
                     TV.TRADEID AS TRADEID,
                     TV.TRD_VER AS TRD_VER,
                     TV.TIMEST AS TIMEST,
                     TV.SOURCENAME AS SOURCENAME,
                     STG_TRADE.SP_COND AS SP_COND
                FROM MASTER_T TV, T_STG_TRADE_VERSION STG_TRADE
               WHERE     TV.SOURCENAME = STG_TRADE.SOURCENAME
                     AND TV.TRADEID = STG_TRADE.TRADEID
                     AND TV.TRD_VER = STG_TRADE.TRD_VER
                     AND TV.TIMEST = STG_TRADE.TIMEST
                     AND TRADESETID = '91004'
            GROUP BY TV.TRADEID,
                     TV.TRD_VER,
                     TV.TIMEST,
                     TV.SOURCENAME,
                     STG_TRADE.SP_COND) TRD
        ON (cc.SP_COND = trd.S_TRD 
        AND trd.S_TRD IS NOT NULL ) --remove this filter ,incase you need to copy the null s_trd value to child_cond when matched
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET cc.S_TRD = trd.S_TRD
```

Comment: But Merge case often fails in case of duplicates coming up

Comment: @user2501620 :So as `UPDATE` , are you sure that TRD returns only one record or null always ? ,if yes then my code will work fine

Comment: @user2501620 The merge query above should work fine, it does exactly what I suggested to you in your OP, it only limit the update to when there is a master-child

Comment: @user2501620:[SQLLINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aa0e/4) , check the explaination in the sqlfiddle link

Comment: For Merge I am getting invalid identifier

Comment: @user2501620:can you please send me the whole exception statement?

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Comment: It could be that there exists some records in master tables but not in child tables , in that case I am getting the above error

Comment: @user2501620:try removing the trd.s_trd is not null filter from the clause

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to update s_trd to null in case the CHILD_COND.SP_COND has no value, you can add the where condition to you update statment:

```
...
WHERE SP_COND IS NOT NULL
```

---

```
    UPDATE CHILD_COND
        SET S_TRD=
          (SELECT S_TRD
          FROM
            (SELECT MAX(TV.S_TRD)            AS S_TRD,
            TV.TRADEID                        AS TRADEID,
            TV.TRD_VER             AS TRD_VER,
            TV.TIMEST                 AS TIMEST,
            TV.SOURCENAME                     AS SOURCENAME,
            STG_TRADE.SP_COND AS SP_COND
            FROM MASTER_T TV,
            T_STG_TRADE_VERSION STG_TRADE
            WHERE TV.SOURCENAME       = STG_TRADE.SOURCENAME
            AND TV.TRADEID            = STG_TRADE.TRADEID
            AND TV.TRD_VER = STG_TRADE.TRD_VER
            AND TV.TIMEST     = STG_TRADE.TIMEST
            AND TRADESETID            = '91004'
            GROUP BY TV.TRADEID,
            TV.TRD_VER,
            TV.TIMEST,
            TV.SOURCENAME,
             STG_TRADE.SP_COND
            )TRD WHERE CHILD_COND.SP_COND = TRD.SP_COND AND S_TRD IS NOT NULL
         )
WHERE SP_COND IS NOT NULL
```